# Print out the objects being written by git push

Tags: git, github

I'm having trouble with pushing a large repository (around 6 GB in size) to git. It gets stuck at 4% and as it seems at a specfic object. Is there any way to find out, which files are causing the trouble?

```
git push
Counting objects: 46546, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (46367/46367), done.
Writing objects:   4% (2289/46541), 495.26 MiB | 8.14 MiB/s
```

Comment: Does `git push --progress --verbose` tell you anything useful?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of any command that displays that information, but you will get way more info by running:

```
GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using https instead of ssh. Switching to the latter solved the problem for me.